# Could not launch “<AppName>” after trying to build to device

Tags: ios, xcode

I just upgraded to Xcode 4.4.1 and bought into the Apple Developer Program. I setup the *Developer* Provisioning profile and got all the proper credentials on my device. Then, when I try to run the app on the device it give the the "Could not lauch '' ". I have tried all the possible combinations of closing xcode, deleting the derived data, restoring the device, and restarting the computer. None of that seems to work. Is anyone else having this issue and how did you solve it when no one else's solution worked?

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting "Required device capabilities" in the -Info.plist file.

You can't require armv7 on a 3G, and you can't require armv6 on any newer device, so just delete this attribute entirely.

Comment: This was it!  All of the starting/stopping/deleting, etc. was not actually the problem.  I am so glad that you posted this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is your device running iOS 6? You need the developer preview of Xcode 4.5 to run apps on devices with iOS 6.

Have you registered your app ID with Apple?

If you go to the Organizer (Window->Organizer), is the light next to your device green?

Comment: I'm not on iOS 6 and I'm using Xcode 4.4.1. The device is green

Comment: If your device is the green the problem may be with your app. Download some of Apple's sample code (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code), open it in Xcode, and see if you can run it.